# Find all pairs of primes $p,q$ such that $pq \mid 2^p +2^q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all pairs of primes $p,q$ such that $pq \mid 2^p +2^q$.

My attempt  : When either one of them is $2$ then easy case checking gives me set of solutions. But what happens when neither of them is $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight tune up to the argument presented in Prometheus' answer (currently deleted, but hopefully soon fixed and undeleted) proves that there are no solutions such that $p$ and $q$ are both odd primes.

**Lemma.** Assume that $p$ is a prime factor of $2^{2^ts}+1$ where $t,s$ are positive integers, $s$ odd. Then
$$
p\equiv1\pmod{2^{t+1}}.
$$

**Proof.** Let $m$ be the order of the residue class of $2$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$.
Because $p\mid 2^{2^ts}+1$, we have $2^{2^ts}\equiv-1\pmod p$, and consequently $2^{2^{t+1}s}\equiv1\pmod p$. This means that $m\mid 2^{t+1}s$ but $m\nmid 2^ts$. Therefore we can conclude that $2^{t+1}\mid m$. But by Lagrange's theorem $m\mid p-1$, so the claim follows.

The rest is easy. Without loss of generality we can assume that $2<p<q$ (the case $p=q$ is obviously impossible). Write $q-p=2^ts$, $s$ odd. The assumption is that
$$
pq\mid 2^p+2^q=2^p(2^{q-p}+1).
$$
This implies that both $p$ and $q$ should be factors of $2^{q-p}+1$. But the Lemma then implies that
$$
p\equiv q\equiv 1\pmod{2^{t+1}}.
$$
This means that $q-p$ is divisible by $2^{t+1}$ contradicting the fact that $s$ is an odd integer by design.

Comment: I didn't understand when you said that $2^{t+1}\mid m$ and $q−p=2^ts$. Could you explain me please?

Comment: @Vmimi $q$ and $p$ are both odd, so there exists a positive integer $t$ and an odd integer $s$ such that $q-p=2^ts$. If $p$ is a factor of $2^p+2^q$ it must also be a factor of $2^{q-p}+1$. The Lemma then says that $p\equiv1\pmod{2^{t+1}}$. Similarly, the Lemma implies that also $q\equiv1\pmod{2^{t+1}}$. But then $q-p$ is divisible by $2^{t+1}$. A contradiction.

Comment: I got that part but what about when you say that $2^{t+1}\mid m$?

Comment: @Vmimi 1) $m$ is a factor of $2^{t+1}s$. 2) $m$ is not a factor of $2^ts$. Therefore $2^{t+1}$ must be a factor of $m$?

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but here’s an alternative solution.

We claim that the only solutions are $(2, 2)$, $(2, 3)$, and $(3, 2)$. Checking, these indeed work.

Suppose at least one of the two primes is $2$---let it be $p$. Then, $2q \mid (2^q + 4)$. So, $2^q \equiv -4 \pmod{q}$. By Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^q \equiv 2 \pmod{q}$, so $q \mid 6$. Thus, $q = 2$ or $q = 3$, both of which work.

Now, suppose both primes are odd. By Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$, so since $2^p + 2^q \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then $2^{q - 1} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. Let $r = \operatorname{ord}_p(2)$. Since $2^{2(q - 1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, then $r \mid 2(q - 1)$, but $r \nmid (q - 1)$. Since $q - 1$ is even, this implies that $r = 2k$ where $k$ is some factor of $q - 1$ such that $\nu_2(k) = \nu_2(q - 1)$. By Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, so $\operatorname{ord}_p(2) = 2k \mid (p - 1)$. Since $\nu_2(2k) > \nu_2(q - 1)$, this implies that $\nu_2(p - 1) > \nu_2(q - 1)$. Similarly, we can show that $\nu_2(q - 1) > \nu_2(p - 1)$, contradiction.