# find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p \cdot q | 2^p + 2^q$

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

> I have to find all prime numbers $p,q$ such that $p\cdot q | 2^p + 2^q$.

I don't know from what I have to start.

Comment: Hint: $2^q\equiv -2^p\equiv -2\pmod p$. So, $2^{2(q-1)}\equiv 1\pmod p$. Now consider the order of $2$ in $\bmod p$

Comment: Why only mod p ? It should not be pq ?

Comment: Well, it is always easier to work in prime numbers. Observe $pq|n$ implies $p|n$.

Comment: Ok i understand, so order 2 in mod p is 2(q-1)

Comment: No, the order divides $2(q-1)$, but not $q-1$, as $2^{q-1}\equiv -1$.

Comment: Yes and  it also order 2 in mod p divides p -1 From fermat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40751/discussion-between-zxc-and-emre).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all pairs of primes $p,q$ such that $pq \mid 2^p +2^q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283026/find-all-pairs-of-primes-p-q-such-that-pq-mid-2p-2q)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p=q$, then, $p^2|2^{p+1}$. So, $p=q=2$.

Now,suppose $p\ne q$.

If $p=2$, we have $q|2+2^{q-1}$. By Fermat's Little Theorem(FLT), $q=3$. Similarly, $q=2,p=3$ is another solution.

Now, suppose $p$ and $q$ are odd primes. Let $p-1=2^ms$ and $q-1=2^nr$, where $r$ and $s$ odd numbers.

$2^q\equiv -2^p\equiv -2\pmod p$. So, $2^{(q-1)}\equiv -1\pmod p$ and $2^{2(q-1)}\equiv 1\pmod p$. Let $k$ be the order of $2$ in $\bmod p$.  Then, $k|2(q-1)=2^{n+1}r$. So, $k=2^{n_0}r_0$ for some $n_0\le n+1$ and $r_0|r$. On the other hand, $k\not\lvert (q-1)$, thus, $n_0> n$.

So, $k=2^{n+1}r_0$. However, by FLT, $k|p-1$, too. So, $m\ge n+1$.

However, $2^p\equiv -2^q\equiv -2\pmod q$. So, $2^{(p-1)}\equiv -1\pmod q$ and $2^{2(p-1)}\equiv 1\pmod q$. Let $l$ be the order of $2$ in $\bmod q$.  Then, $l|2(p-1)=2^{m+1}s$. So, $l=2^{m_0}s_0$ for some $m_0\le m+1$ and $s_0|s$. On the other hand, $l\not\lvert (p-1)$, thus, $m_0> m$.

So, $l=2^{m+1}s_0$. However, by FLT, $l|q-1$, too. So, $n\ge m+1$.

However, we get 
$$n\ge m+1\ge n+2$$
Contradiction.Thus, $(2,2),(2,3),(3,2)$ are the only solutions.