# Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $pq\mid 2^p+2^q$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Find all $p,q$ primes such that $pq\mid 2^p+2^q$.

$Case 1(p=q=2)$ Then it satisfies condition of problem.

$Case 2(p=2,q\neq2)$. Then by Fermat's little theorem, $q\mid6\implies q=3$. It means $6\mid 12$ which satisfies condition of problem.

$Case 3(p,q\neq2)$. By Fermat's little theorem, $2^{p-1}\equiv -1(mod q)$ and $2^{q-1}\equiv -1(mod p)$. It means $2^{p+q-2}\equiv -1(mod pq)$. Now I don't know how to continue. Anyone can continue this?

Comment: Another duplicate is [find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p \cdot q | 2^p + 2^q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1814440/602049).