# Number of ordered pairs of primes (p,q) such that pq divides (2^p+2^q).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was trying to solve a question given as follows:

Find all ordered pairs of primes (p,q) such that pq divides (2^p+2^q).

I have been able to solve a bit of it and I am sharing what I have done:

I have broken the problem into four cases among which three of them has been solved by me. The cases are as follows:

Case 1: p=2 and q=2 is an obvious solution.

Case 2: if p=2 and q≠2 then only I have got the only possible solution as (p,q)=(2,3).

Case 3: if p≠2 and q=2 then I have got the only possible solution as (p,q)=(3,2).

Case 4: if p≠2 and also q≠2 , then I am unable to approach further.

Please help me with a way to solve  the fourth case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all pairs of primes $p,q$ such that $pq \mid 2^p +2^q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283026/find-all-pairs-of-primes-p-q-such-that-pq-mid-2p-2q)

Comment: flagged it as a duplicate :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to both of you and yes that link does answer my question.